How do atomics vs mutexes differ in terms of cacheline synchronization
I know there are many discrepancies between them, e.g., atomics may incur spinning while mutexes may involve blocking.
But what I want to know is how they differ in terms of cacheline synchronization.
To be specific, is the following assertion correct, or can you correct it if not?

The atomics may only synchronize data on certain dirty cachelines, while mutexes may synchronize all dirty cachelines and empty related buffers.

I really appreciate any advice and suggestions.

With atomics, if an acquire load sees a value from a release store, all cache lines modified before the release store are visible to the thread that did the acquire load (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  If you only rely on data dependency order (C++'s memory_order_consume), then yes you only have synchronization for the pointed-to cache line, not all cache lines.

Or with relaxed atomics, there's no synchronization of any other values.  (Potentially not even in the same cache line; store-forwarding between logical cores like on PowerPC can also cause IRIW reordering.)

Thank you, @PeterCordes! Is cacheline synchronization language-dependent? In other words, do atomic operations and mutexes work differently in languages like Java, Go, Rust, or others? By the way, I've read many of your posts and learned a lot. I sincerely respect you!

Cache lines are a feature of CPU architecture.  Other than assembly language, no language gives guarantees in terms of cache lines, only the high-level language's memory model.  (All of which are in terms of release-store / acquire-load, or consume style data-dependency ordering, if they provide anything weaker than seq_cst.)  One aspect of hardware cache coherency that does get make it into a high-level memory model is C++ which gives coherence guarantees for ops on a single location, but that's not synchronization.  https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19
